# How to connect R with PostgreSQL on OSX 10.10.2?

Tags: r, macos, postgresql, odbc, rodbc

I have the following setup:

- OSX 10.10.2
- PostgreSQL 9.4.1
- R 3.1.3

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5869941/604388) as of 2011 says that the easiest approach is to use `RpgSQL` package. But it is [removed](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RpgSQL/) from the CRAN repository. `RODBC` mentioned there is available [as source](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/), but it fails to configure:

```
configure: error: "ODBC headers sql.h and sqlext.h not found"
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RODBC’
```

I've also found another package, which could help me - [`RPostgreSQL`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RPostgreSQL/index.html), but it fails to compile:

```
In file included from RS-PQescape.c:7:
./RS-PostgreSQL.h:23:14: fatal error: 'libpq-fe.h' file not found
#    include "libpq-fe.h"
             ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [RS-PQescape.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RPostgreSQL’
```

Is there any other way to connect R and PostgreSQL?

Comment: How did you install PostgreSQL? `RPostgreSQL` compiles fine on my OS X 10.10.2 system. I use the Homebrew version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: @hrbrmstr, I've downloaded the package http://get.enterprisedb.com/postgresql/postgresql-9.4.1-3-osx.dmg and installed it. Btw, installation fails (like described there - http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/201107190838.p6J8cwgf039126@wwwmaster.postgresql.org), but I've created user `postgres` manually as described there - http://www.giannakidis.info/post/51891050503/installing-postgresql-9-2-on-mac-os-x

Comment: And, `include` folder of PostgreSQL contains that `libpq-fe.h` file.

Comment: @hrbrmstr, installation of PostgreSQL thru Homebrew helped to resolve the problem with RPostgreSQL. Please post it as the answer, so I will be able to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

See [RODBC to connect to SQL Server on Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419243/rodbc-to-connect-to-sql-server-on-mavericks)

RODBC isn't really supported on OSX. 
What I ended up doing is to use RJDBC, which is in CRAN.
Setting up the connection to your data base isn't always easy. But it can be done:
[Postgres DB can't connect to R with RJDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059378/postgres-db-cant-connect-to-r-with-rjdbc)